# Почему не срабатывает вывод данных из MySQL в HTML-таблицу?

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>DB</title>
</head>
<body>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>age</th>
            <th>salary</th>
        </tr><br>
<?php

    $host = 'localhost';
    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '123QWErty';
    $db_name ='test_db' ;
    $table = '`people`';

    $link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pass, $db_name) or die (mysqli_error($link));
    mysqli_set_charset($connect, 'utf8');

    $query = " SELECT * FROM $table";

    $mysqlquery = mysqli_query($link, $query);
    mysqli_close($link);


    while ($result = mysqli_fetch_array($mysqlquery, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {


    echo "<tr><td>$result['id']</td><td>$result['name']</td><td>$result['age']</td><td>$result['salary']</td></tr><br>";

    } 


    ?>
        </table>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: А зачем вы в конце каждой строки добавляете `<br>`?

Comment: Добрый день. Вы закрыли соединение и потом продолжаете пытаться работать с базой.

Comment: Всем спасибо, задача решена: в случае с элементом массива, переменная его содержащая должна быть экранирована при выводе через echo.